# pandas scatter, timedata and size of point

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My DataFrame looks that:

[image]

I plot it by this code:

```
tmp['event_name'].plot(style='.', figsize=(20,10), grid=True)
```

Results looks that:
[image]

I want to change size of points( using column details). 
Question:
How can I do it? Plot haven't argument size and I can not using plot.scatter() because I can not use time format for x axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) passes any unknown keywords down to `Matplotlib.Artist`, as stated in the linked docs. Therefore, you can specify the marker size using the general matplotlib syntax `ms`:

```
tmp['event_name'].plot(style='.', figsize=(20,10), grid=True, ms=5)
```

That said, you can use `plt.scatter` with time stamps as well, which makes using the 'details' column as marker size more straight forward:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = {'time':       ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04'],
        'event_name': [2, 2, 2, 2],
        'details':    [46, 16, 1, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dates = [pd.to_datetime(date) for date in df.time]
plt.scatter(dates, df.event_name, s=df.details)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I was surprised that the autoscale doesn't work with pandas datetime index. You can easily fix this, but any idea, why this happens in matplotlib?

Comment: @Mr.T How can I fix it pandas?

Comment: `plt.xlim(df.index.min()-1, df.index.max()+1)` BTW, it is bad style not to provide a toy dataset. Not only made you poor madoee type data from a picture, you both have as a result a different data structure.

Comment: @Mr.T I was wondering about this as well. [This mpl site](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html) suggests that it is a data structure issue and lists some easy fixes for the arising problems.

Comment: The linked page does not seem to relate to scaling issues at all. Apart, part of what this page tells us is already out of date, seen from the fact that your solution above works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try so:

```
for index, i in enumerate(df['details']):
    plt.plot(df.index[index], df.iloc[index]['event_name'], marker='.', linestyle='None', markersize=i*4, color='b')
plt.show()
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = {'time': ['2015-01-01','2015-01-02','2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05'],'event_name': [2,2,2,2,2], 'details':[46,16,1,7,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index('time')
```

df:

```
                details  event_name
time                           
2015-01-01       46           2
2015-01-02       16           2
2015-01-03        1           2
2015-01-04        7           2
2015-01-05        4           2
```

Output:

[image]